# Create a search box that returns several hidden text values

Tags: html, forms, search

I'm a bit of a newb.  So please reply slowly, kidding (but really, please respond with basics, links to tutorials, or code).

I'd like to create a search box on my site that will return variables on the page (like below or next to the search box).

Basically, I want to perform something like an excel vlookup, but in html....where I type A, hit submit and B, C, and D are returned.  I'm also willing to do a dropdown, that (again) after selected will return B, C, and D (B,C, and D being text only). I've searched for this and come up with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

i found something like this...

```
Array.prototype.vlookup = function(needle,index,exactmatch){

        index = index || 0;
        exactmatch = exactmatch || false;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            var row = this[i];

            if ((exactmatch && row[0]===needle) || row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                return (index < row.length ? row[index] : row[0]);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

this is the source http://brad-christie.com/blog/2011/03/02/vlookup-for-javascript/

give it a try...!